# Geometry in $\mathbb{R}^n$: angle between projections of a rectangle

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, convex-geometry, euclidean-geometry, affine-geometry

Consider a hyper rectangle $R$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ defined by $|x_i|\leq M_i$ for all $i\leq n$.
Consider a linear affine subspace $L$ of dimension $1\leq k <n$ such that $L\cap R\neq \emptyset$.
For all $x \in R\setminus L$, we define the point $x'\in L\cap R$ that minimizes the euclidian distance of $x$ to $L\cap R$. We also denote by $x_{\perp}$ the orthogonal projection of $x$ on $L$. If $\alpha_x$ is the angle between the vectors $x'-x$ and $x_{\perp}-x$, I would like to prove that $\inf_{x\in R\setminus L} |\cos(\alpha_x)|>0$. Looking at dimension 2, it seems to me that this is a reasonable conjecture but I was not able to prove it. Can someone give a help please?

Answer (score 0):

Let $\ell$ be a perpendicular line to $L$.
We can assume that $\ell$ does not lie in a coordinate hyperplane (otherwise, the question can be reduced to a lower-dimensional case).
Denote by $\alpha$ the maximal angle between $\ell$ and the coordinate lines; note that $\alpha<\tfrac\pi2$.

Look at the tangent cone at $x'$.
Note that $\alpha_x$ is the angle between $\ell$ and $x-x'$.
Observe that there is a supporting hyperplane $\Pi$ to $R$ thru $x'$ such that $(x_\perp-x' )\perp(L\cap \Pi)$.
Moreover, we may assume that $\Pi$ contains an edge of $R$.
Denote by $\beta$ the angle between $\Pi$ and $\ell$.
Note that $\alpha\geqslant \beta\geqslant \alpha_x$ --- hence your statement.

Comment: Can you detail/prove the claim "$\alpha_x$ does not exceed the maximal angle between $\ell$ and the coordinate lines"? Also, I think the conjecture in the OP will hold if the hyper-rectangle is replaced by any polytope. What do you think about this?

Comment: @IosifPinelis Sure, the same proof works for any polytope. Feel free to add details.

Comment: But, again, can you detail/prove the claim "$\alpha_x$ does not exceed the maximal angle between $\ell$ and the coordinate lines" -- at least in the case of a hyper-rectangle? And how would this generalize to polytopes?

Comment: @IosifPinelis look at the extremal rays of the tangent cone to $R$ at $x'$.

Comment: I am looking. Now what?

Comment: @IosifPinelis Sorry, don't you see that the extremal rays are parallel to the edges?

Comment: I can see that. So what?

Comment: @IosifPinelis You are interested in maximal angle $<\tfrac\pi 2$ between $\ell$ and such direction, is not it?

Comment: I guess I can kind of see your point now. Still, it would be good if you just added all the details to your answer.

Comment: @IosifPinelis You are quite persistent.

Comment: Mr. Petrunin, Thank you for your answer! I am trying to understand it fully. I a
Could you please explain how you define the tangent cone at $x'$? Also, I still do not understand the definition of $\Pi$. You define $\Pi$ as a supporting hyperplane of $R$ through $x'$ but $x'$ is not necessarily a boundary point of $R$. Thanks.

Comment: @Alainty The tangent cone is formed by all half-lines from $x'$ that spend some time in $R$. If $x'$ is not a boundary point, then $x'=x_\perp$ ant there is nothing to prove.

Comment: I realize I am a little bit late on this post but anyway I am interested in finding a detailed answer to this problem! I looked at A. Petrunin's answer but I also have some comment: When you fix some $\ell$ perpendicular to $L$ you can have many choices if $L$ is not a hyperplane. As a consequence $\alpha_x$ is not in general the angle between $\ell$ and $x-x'$.

Comment: Dear Franck, I think we can simplify the problem by considering only  the $x$'s that belong to the edges of $R$ (by edge I mean the segment between two adjacent vertex of $R$). Then, by a simple compactness argument, you only have to prove the result for the edges that intersect $L$.